# svn-update entered option (s- for all option) isn't executed

Tags: svn, svn-update

I desperately try to get a entered option for the command `svn update` executed. My issue is that when a versioned file is in conflict and I run the command `svn update` I do get provided the options, like `s`-showing all options or `r`-resolve.

However when I enter the letter `s` for example on the command line nothing happens or I don't get any response showing that something is going on. I already wait at least 30 minutes after entering  the letter but nothing happens. I also searched several forums and web sites but I couldn't find any related issues.

So did any one experience the same issue or may know what I do wrong?

Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SVN are you using? According to the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html), there is no `-s` option for the `svn update` command...

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? Automatic conflict resolution ?

Comment: Hello,

I'm using Subversion 1.7.3. It doesn't matter which option I enter nothing happens from my experience. Yes, I would like to accept the server version or my local version by entering one of the provided options. I know I can do a manual diff and mark the file as resolved. However somehow my option aren't accepted. I will try it once more.